# Existe uma maneira de evitar as especificações de tamanho no layout do Android?

Tags: java, android

Eu trabalho com Android no dia-a-dia, e eu gostaria de evitar as especificações do tamanho visualizações. Por exemplo: Se eu fizer um `TextView`, eu tenho que atribuir propriedades Altura e Largura, assim:

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/activity_lbl"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" <!-- Novamente -->
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!-- Novamente...  --> /> 

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/activity_lbl2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" <!-- Novamente... -->
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!-- Novamente....  --> />
```

Existe uma maneira de evitar as especificações de tamanho no layout do Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode definir um ou vários "styles" para seu projeto

Ex.:
Seu ***TextView*** ficará assim:

`<TextView style="@style/TextWidth" android:text="@string/textOne" />`

Seu ***style*** ficará assim:

```
<style name="TextWidth">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
</style>
```

Fonte: [Blog Caelum](http://blog.caelum.com.br/usando-styles-nos-layouts-da-sua-aplicacao-android/)